# Запрет переноса по дефисам

Tags: css, textarea

В textarea сложные слова (ярко-красный, Сан-Паулу, например) переносятся по дефисам. Как сделать так, чтобы, если слово сложное, то переносилось полностью? Чтобы слова переносились только по пробелам нужно как то сделать. Может надо скрипт какой или можно css?

Comment: можно использовать символ [неразрывный дефис](https://symbl.cc/ru/2011/)

Comment: @Grundy, а можно как то автоматизировать? За всеми дефисами ведь не уследишь :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте применить hyphens: none;

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/hyphens

Comment: Это работает, но тогда съедается дефис и получается яркокрасный, СанПаулу

Comment: По старым правилам русского языка слова переносятся по дефису. если у вас в <html> указано lang="ru" то перенос по дефису у вас будет, там как раз так в словарях. Посмотрите возможность через js заменять обычный дефис на неразрывный, например регулярным выражением

Comment: да, придётся при сохранении написать что то типа `$content = str_replace('-', '‑', $content)`.